# How to get url of youtube video which has mp4 format through code

Tags: java, android, youtube, youtube-api

I have my own video player which only supports mp4 format. So i need to provide it with mp4 format video.

I am parsing the content which i am getting from youtube data api. Currently youtube provide the video content in swf format or flash format with chromeless player. But i want to get the url which has video in mp4 format. I cannot make use of other softwares like keepvid etc to convert that link into mp4 format. I want it to get done through code only.

Please suggest something.

Comment: Write your own code to convert the youtube vieo into mp4 format.

Comment: Maybe JMF would be a solution for you? http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html

Comment: @Vulcan: But we can get mp4 format from the Keepvid.com. And they provide the url to download the file . So it means that they are not converting the video. There must be some easy way to get it done.

Comment: @Robin: Sorry i forgot to mention that i am doing it in android. I dont know if JMF will support in android.